# Apache bypass URL based on Header

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Am looking to by pass url based on value on header , 
when request coming to apache server will inspect the header and if value = test1

> it will rewrite proxy pass url  exampel :

```
www.demo.test.com  >> to
```

> www.end.test.com

if the value is null it will by pass the url to

```
www.null.test.com
```

what is the best way to test  this case

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect HTTP headers with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Some-Header} test1
RewriteRule ^ http://www.demo.test.com [L]
```

---

Based on the comments, when `index.html` is requested and a header `Video: Provider1` is sent, rewrite to `demo.test.com/provide1/m3u8.mp4`. If the header is `Video: Provider2`, rewrite to `demo.test.com/provide/m3u8.mp4`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Video} ^Provider1$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://demo.test.com/provide1/m3u8.mp4 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Video} ^Provider2$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://demo.test.com/provide/m3u8.mp4 [L]
```

Comment: I dont want to redirect the url itself , i want redirect  specific  "sub url" it will be request inside the code

Comment: I don't understand that. If you don't want to rewrite based on a HTTP header, what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: ill explain it in better way :

Comment: use connect to www.demo.com

Comment: ill request www.mysite.com/index.html

Ive coustom headers value  Video: Provider1   Or Video: Provider2

- If the value is Porvider 1 I want to :

in js code in the html; there is url called demo.mysite.com  i need it to re-wrtie and replaced by   demo.test.com/provide1/m3u8.mp4 when ever its requested
 
- If the value is Provider 2 I want to 

in js code in the html; there is url called demo.mysite.com  i need it to re-wrtie and replaced by  demo.test.com/provide/m3u8.mp4 when ever its requested

Comment: I don't understand the *: in js code in the html* part. But this is out of scope for Apache's mod_rewrite anyway. You should clarify and add this info to your question. In any case, please see updated answer.